# Running django on 0.0.0.0:8000

Tags: python, django

I am using vagrant along with Virtualbox, so I can't `runserver` on the default port and address or it won't work.

Django says:

```
(...) to listen on all public IPs (useful if you want to show off your work on 
other computers), use:

python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

Then I tried to access the server via `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` but it says `Unable to connect`. Any guess how to run the server correctly?

I have followed the `gettingstartedwithdjango` vidoes and this `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` worked for the author.

Comment: Note that it says 8000 but you say you tried to access it at 8888

Comment: None of these work. I have followed `gettingstartedwithdjango` vidoes and this `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` worked for the author.

Comment: Do you have port 8000 properly forwarded? Do you have Vagrant's IP set in `INTERNAL_IPS` in your settings?

Comment: @OndrejSlinták hmm it might be the case, can you elaborate on how to set those INTERNAL_IPS settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run with root privileges. If you run with `sudo`you will succeed.

**UPDATE 1**

The previous information is irrelevant with the topic.
In vagrant you have to forward your port to a local port. Please have a look at [this](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/getting-started/ports.html).

**UPDATE 2**

[This page](http://blog.smalleycreative.com/tutorials/setup-a-django-vm-with-vagrant-virtualbox-and-chef/) explained how to install and configure django in a vagrant box.

Comment: False, every port above 1024 can be used by a normal user without root privileges.

Answer (score 5):

For people who are just looking where to configure the IP, it is run like so (as seen in the OP) -

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

If you are accessing it over your local network you will also need to update `settings.py` with the IP of your host, as well as specifying `localhost`. Your local IP can be gotten on Windows by running `ipconfig` in the command prompt, or `ip addr show` in the terminal on Ubuntu.

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.XXX', 'localhost']
```