# how to proper setup ALLOWED_HOST to allow other machine in the network access the web

Tags: python, django

Django server in machine TestPC-A, at 192.25.56.120

I want it accessible from the computer in the same network 192.25.56.xxx.

what I have configured

**1. settings.py**

```py
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["127.0.0.1", "localhost", "TestPC-A" , "0.0.0.0", "192.25.56.120"]

#and this which I am not sure if this is necessary:

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://127.0.0.1",
    "https://127.0.0.1",
    "http://localhost",
    "https://localhost",
    "https://TestPC-A",
    "http://TestPC-A",
]
```

**2. runserver.bat**

```
@echo off
REM Activate virtual environment in the current terminal session and run server
cmd /k ".venv\Scripts\activate && python manage.py runserver_plus --cert-file cert.pem --key-file key.pem 0.0.0.0:8000"
```

I have tried to add following in Windows hosts file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

```
192.25.56.120    TestPC-A
```

I restart the server, and the web page is not loaded at another computer's web browser `https://TestPC-A:8000/`

What else that I need to set?

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari I could not understand what is your solution.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari what do you mean by *”`ALLOWED_HOSTS` is not that useful”*?

Comment: i have stated "runserver.bat" , what is wrong over there?

Comment: No @AnkitTiwari. `ALLOWED_HOSTS` is a list of particular hosts allowed to host the application.

Comment: If your machine connects to a network, and an IP of `192.168.32.1` is assigned to the machine for example, You must add this address to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` so that Django will allow the machine with this address to host the application.

Comment: I repeat: *when your machine connects to a network, it gets assigned a unique address (IP) to be identifiable on the network. With this IP, Django will allow it to host the application if you add this address to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`. Other machines on the same network can then visit the application if they visit the IP address and the port the application is available on*.

Comment: Well the statement is false. Your use of ***restricts*** is what’s false.

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari I have set this, but no luck, still other computer cannot access it.
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

Comment: on web browser: "http://serverIP:8000" or "http://serverHostname:8000" both no response

Comment: @Ankit Tiwari
 I hope you stop comment mis-leading stuff.

Comment: Hello @user2201789, I apologize if you found my comments  mis-leading to you. Here are some useful resources, setup `ALLOWED_HOSTS` like this as mentioned in this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68217208/14457833), read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5768853/14457833) & if it's there any firewall please enable access for port 8000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For posterity. *To make your development server viewable to other machines on the network.*

Suppose you have two machines `machine A` and `machine B`. Connect both machines to a common network (may even be your mobile phone’s wifi).

If `machine A` will be your server i.e. `machine A` is the machine where your source code has been all this while and `machine A` is where you have been running command:

```py
python manage.py runserver
```

[Check the IP address `machine A` was assigned on this network. <sup>[stackoverflow]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64082218/16770846) Add this IP address to Django settings [`ALLOWED_HOSTS` <sup>[django-docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts) `list` so that Django will allow the machine to host it.

If the IP address is `172.200.42.1` for example, add this to `ALLOWED_HOSTS` and now run the command:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:7000 # <—- runserver on port 7000 on this host on this network
```

Since `machine B` is connected to the same network as `machine A`, use any http-client (even your internet browser can serve) on `machine B` to connect to `machine A` i.e. your server using the socket address `172.200.42.1:7000` <sup>[1]</sup>.

---

<sub>[1] We will use this socket address because the application is running on `machine A` which is at IP address `172.200.42.1` on the network and the application is running on port `7000`.</sub>

Comment: *Why is the application running on port 7000? Can’t it run on port 8000?* **Yes it can**. You can even choose to run it on port 3000, 3030, 5050, 5123, 8080 e.t.c. As long as no other application is running on that port on the host. If there is, and you badly need that port, then you will have to stop the application for yours to run on the desired port.

Comment: One of your machines could also offer the common network. What matters is that the two machines are on the same network so that they can both communicate with each other.

Answer (score -1):

What I have done:

1. `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]`
2. runserver
3. Important: add **inbound rule** at firewall, allow the connection applies to domain,private,public, TCP ThePort

Comment: **Don’t use `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]` in production. It is prone to cyber attack.**